# Fancybox Gallery: carousel view error on Multiple galleries

Tags: javascript, carousel, fancybox

`enter code here`# Problem with Fancybox Gallery #
*Problem with Multiple galleries in the Carousel view*

> My problem is! 
> Category1 shows all images in the carousel instead of only Category1. 
> For Category2 to Category5, everything display correctly. 
> With All, everything show as it should. 
> Issue, as already mentioned, only in Category1.
> Have tryed many things on the

> I hope you can help me here

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;600;700&display=swap");

 /*===== VARIABLES CSS =====*/
 :root {
    --header-height: 3rem;
    --font-medium: 500;
}
/*===== Colores =====*/
:root {
    --first-color: #49A687;
    --complementary-color: #F99D6E;
    --white-color: #FAFAFF;
    --dark-color: #2A3B47;
    --text-color: #697477;
    --white-color-glass: rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.4);
}
/*===== Fuente y tipografia =====*/
:root {
    --body-font: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    --big-font-size: 6.25rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --normal-font-size: .938rem;
    --small-font-size: .813rem;
}

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:  'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
section.res__gallery
{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
section.res__gallery ul
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
section.res__gallery ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    background: var(--first-color);
    color: var(--white-color);
    font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-user-select: None;
    -moz-user-select: None;
    -webkit-user-select: None;
    user-select: None;
}
section.res__gallery ul li.active
{
    background: var(--complementary-color);
    color: var(--white-color);
}
.product
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-user-select: None;
    -moz-user-select: None;
    -webkit-user-select: None;
    user-select: None;
}
.product .itembox
{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
}
.product .itembox.hide
{
    display: none;
}
.product .itembox img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

a[data-fancybox] img {
    cursor: zoom-in;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Responsive Gallery</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery-style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="res__gallery">
            <ul>
                <li class="list active" data-filter="all">Alles</li>
                <li class="list" data-filter="category1">category1</li>
                <li class="list" data-filter="category2">category2</li>
                <li class="list" data-filter="category3">category3</li>
                <li class="list" data-filter="category4">category4</li>
                <li class="list" data-filter="category5">category5</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category1">
                    <a data-mobile="category1" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile1.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images//mobile1.jpg" alt="mobile1" title="Mobile1">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category2">
                    <a data-fancybox="category2" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/camera1.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/camera1.jpg" alt="camera1">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category3">
                    <a data-fancybox="category3" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/watch1.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/watch1.jpg" alt="watch1">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category4">
                    <a data-fancybox="category4" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/shoe1.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/shoe1.jpg" alt="shoe1">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category5">
                    <a data-fancybox="category5" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/headphone1.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/headphone1.jpg" alt="headphone1">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category1">
                    <a data-mobile="category1" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile2.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile2.jpg" alt="mobile2">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category2">
                    <a data-fancybox="category2" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/camera2.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/camera2.jpg" alt="camera2">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category3">
                    <a data-fancybox="category3" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/watch2.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/watch2.jpg" alt="watch2">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category4">
                    <a data-fancybox="category4" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/shoe2.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/shoe2.jpg" alt="shoe2">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category5">
                    <a data-fancybox="category5" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/headphone2.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/headphone2.jpg" alt="headphone2">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category1">
                    <a data-mobile="category1" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile3.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile3.jpg" alt="mobile3">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category2">
                    <a data-fancybox="category2" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/camera3.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/camera3.jpg" alt="camera3">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category3">
                    <a data-fancybox="category3" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/watch3.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/watch3.jpg" alt="watch3">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category4">
                    <a data-fancybox="category4" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/shoe3.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/shoe3.jpg" alt="shoe3">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category5">
                    <a data-fancybox="category5" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/headphone3.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/headphone3.jpg" alt="headphone3">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category1">
                    <a data-mobile="category1" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile4.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile4.jpg" alt="mobile4">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category3">
                    <a data-fancybox="category3" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/watch4.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/watch4.jpg" alt="watch4">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category4">
                    <a data-fancybox="category4" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/shoe4.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/shoe4.jpg" alt="shoe4">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category5">
                    <a data-fancybox="category5" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/headphone4.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/headphone4.jpg" alt="headphone4">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="itembox" data-item="category1">
                    <a data-mobile="category1" data-caption="Short caption" href="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile5.jpg">
                        <img src="https://mectag-design.com/assets/images/mobile5.jpg" alt="mobile5">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


        <script>
            let list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
            let itemBox = document.querySelectorAll('.itembox');

            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                list[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                        list[j].classList.remove('active');
                    }
                    this.classList.add('active');

                    let dataFilter = this.getAttribute('data-filter');

                    for (let k = 0; k < itemBox.length; k++) {
                        itemBox[k].classList.remove('active');
                        itemBox[k].classList.add('hide');
                        Fancybox.bind(
                            '[data-mobile="category0"],[data-mobile="category1"],[data-fancybox="category2"],[data-fancybox="category3"],[data-fancybox="category4"],[data-fancybox="category5"]',
                            {
                                groupAll: false,
                            }
                        );


                        if (itemBox[k].getAttribute('data-item') == dataFilter ||
                            dataFilter == "all") {
                            itemBox[k].classList.remove('hide');
                            itemBox[k].classList.add('active');
                            Fancybox.bind(
                                '[data-mobile="category0"],[data-mobile="category1"],[data-fancybox="category2"],[data-fancybox="category3"],[data-fancybox="category4"],[data-fancybox="category5"]',
                                {
                                    groupAll: true,
                                }
                            );
                        }

                    }
                })
            }


        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to update selector to something like `Fancybox.bind('[data-mobile="category0"].active', {});` because Fancybox displays every item that matches your selector, e.g., it internally uses something similar to `document.querySelectorAll(YOUR_SELECTOR)`

Comment: Thanks, it works now I knew it, it must be a little thing that this works!